# AWS Managed apache airflow task is stuck at 'queue' status and never run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have created DAG using AWS Managed airflow. My task is getting stuck at queue status and never run .I need to delete and redeploy the DAG to make it run. If I trigger it again after successful run. I am facing same issue.

Please help me with the issue and let me know how i can check airflow scheduler in aws console